# React/CSS - Animate button width resize after content changes when width is auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have a react component representing a button which changes the content and color depending on some `props`. If a form component includes this button and gets submitted the button changes it's content and color. This works well.

Now I want an animation (CSS transition) for the changing with when the content of the button changes. **Setting an explicit `width` for different states is NOT an option because the application is multilingual**. When using `max-width` the animation only works when the button extends but not when it decreases.

Here is a snippet with a button component which changes the state every second. Like in the real component this one uses the bootstrap `btn` classes:

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {status: 0};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  tick() {
    let status = this.state.status;
    status++;
    if(status >= 2) {
      status = 0;
    }
    this.setState({
      status: status
    });
  }

  render() {
    const btnClass = this.state.status ? 'primary' : 'secondary';
    
    return (
      <button className={`btn btn-${btnClass}`} type='button'>
        {this.state.status ? this.props.large : this.props.short}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Button large='This is a long button you can click on!' short='short'/>,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.btn {
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: max-width 1s;
    width: auto;
}

.btn-primary {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.btn-secondary {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

## How can i get an animation for the changing `width` (when the button gets smaller again)?

Please consider that an answer doesn't have to be just CSS related. I thought about that the react component calculates it's width and then sets it inside the `componentWillMount` function but that didn't work either...

Comment: To make animation of `max-width` possible simply change the `transition: width ...` statement to either `transition: max-width...` or remove a specified property to transition all of them. Still, animating max-width can be jerky since you dont really know exaclty how wide the button is depending on language/screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution. Add min-width to your css classes and transition as below.

Animate on the way up. Animate on the way down.

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {status: 0};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  tick() {
    let status = this.state.status;
    status++;
    if(status >= 2) {
      status = 0;
    }
    this.setState({
      status: status
    });
  }

  render() {
    const btnClass = this.state.status ? 'primary' : 'secondary';
    
    return (
      <button className={`btn btn-${btnClass}`} type='button'>
        {this.state.status ? this.props.large : this.props.short}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Button large='This is a long button you can click on!' short='short'/>,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.btn {
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari */
     transition: max-width 1s, min-width 1s;
     width: auto;
}

.btn-primary {
  max-width: 330px;
  min-width: 230px;
}

.btn-secondary {
  max-width: 60px;
  min-width: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `width: 100%` to `.btn` class. There is nothing wrong with animating `max-width` property. The issue arises when the text is changing from a small text to a larger one and the browser will have to recalculate what `auto` means as a value for the `width` property. It seems that `100%` does not work the same way.

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {status: 0};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  tick() {
    let status = this.state.status;
    status++;
    if(status >= 2) {
      status = 0;
    }
    this.setState({
      status: status
    });
  }

  render() {
    const btnClass = this.state.status ? 'primary' : 'secondary';
    
    return (
      <button className={`btn btn-${btnClass}`} type='button'>
        {this.state.status ? this.props.large : this.props.short}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Button large='This is a long button you can click on!' short='short'/>,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.btn {
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: max-width 1s;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-primary {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.btn-secondary {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```